# Invoke Powershell Cmd for Add-AppxPackage Remove-AppPackage using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a small C# program to uninstall and reinstall windows appxpackages.
I've used many of the powershell commands manually and they all work fine if ran via powershell however I would like to just make a button that runs the command without having to go look up the command then copy paste it into the prompt window. I've researched this method for a few days now and I've not found anything helpful. 
Everywhere I look other users have done something like this however while this will compile this will not do anything. Perhaps I am just not seeing something or perhaps not understanding something. Can anyone please help!

```
Powershell commands:
Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Add-AppxPackage
```

.

```
using System.Management.Automation;
```

.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.AddCommand("Get-AppxPackage");
    ps.AddArgument("*windowsstore*");
    ps.AddCommand("Remove-AppxPackage");
    ps.Invoke();
    Console.WriteLine("POWERSHELL OUTPUT! =( "+ps+" )");
}
```

Output:
    POWERSHELL OUTPUT! =( System.Management.Automation.PowerShell )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK scratch that. Its to convoluted and I've stopped caring.

This is what I did to solve my problem. I hope someone else will find this helpful.

```
        //Make a folder to keep everything together.
        if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\\Folder"))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\\Folder");

        var result = string.Empty;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                //Download the string of text for the command from a file on the server.
                // the command is just this.
                //Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
                result = webClient.DownloadString("http://MyServer.net/scripts/ReinstallWinApps.ps1");

                //Create a .ps1 file and dump the result into it then save.
                FileStream file = new FileStream(@"C:\\Folder\\ReinstallWinApps.ps1", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                StreamWriter print_text = new StreamWriter(file);
                print_text.Write(result);
                print_text.Close();

                //Run the file as admin.
                ProcessStartInfo PS = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\\Folder\\ReinstallWinApps.ps1");
                PS.UseShellExecute = true;
                PS.Verb = "runas";
                Process.Start( PS );
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

If you find a better way to do this please give back to the world. 
I spent a week trying to get the powershell method working and no dice. 
I wish you all the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the `PowerShell` object directly, while what you want to do is take the output of `ps.Invoke()` and process and print that.

Excerpt from the [example in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(
            "{0,-24}{1}",
            result.Members["ProcessName"].Value,
            result.Members["Id"].Value);
  }
```

Here you can see how the output of `ps.Invoke()` is handled.

If you want the output as text:

```
foreach (PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", result);
}
```

Comment: This is the output with the foreach line added.                                                                                                                    The thread 0x143a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: The problem is that nothing happens at all when the command is ran. The lack of any useful output info is really frustrating.

Comment: Then I suggest you start debugging. Try different things. Run only a single command, not a pipeline, run a command that you know outputs something. Step in the debugger. Inspect the program. Investigate.

Comment: What do you expect to get as an output? See the documentation for `Remove-AppxPackage` (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856038.aspx). Hint: "Output, none"